# Show that the best mean square estimator of $X$ given $(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ is $\hat X =E[X|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{n})]$

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $X_{i}$,  $i=1,...,n$ be random variables on a probability space $(\Omega , \mathcal F,P)$. Show that the best mean square estimator of $X$ given $(X_{1},...,X_{n})$ is  $\hat X =E[X|\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{n})]$

Comment: I'm adding self-study tag, since it clearly appropriate. It would help if you add where you're stuck.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the conditional expectation as a projection in a $L^2$ space ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent. I dont khow this definition but if this problem solve whit definition i find and read it.thanks

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent 
I think in the near future I will learn this definition

Comment: Ok but what is your definition of the conditional expectation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? Take a look: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52631/conditional-expectation-has-the-minimum-mean-prediction-error/52663#52663

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent. my definition is if $P(\Lambda_{n})>0$ the function $E[X|\mathcal G]:\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb R$Are defined as follows:
$$E[X|\mathcal G](\omega)=\sum_{n}E[X|\Lambda_{n}]\upharpoonleft_{n}$$
$$E[X|\Lambda_{n}]=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega) P_{\Lambda_{n}}(d\omega)=\frac{1}{P(\Lambda_{n})}\int_{\Lambda_{n}}X(\omega) P(d\omega)$$

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent. i Send to definition What is your opinion?

Comment: @zen.my definition of the conditional expectation is in my profile are you think The answer is the same link that you put in my profile?

Comment: The $X_i$ are discrete random variables ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent.Not to mention in the question

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent.this definition is true for both.