# Why is that the mean forecasting error is minimized when Conditional Expectation is used

Tags: arma

As the title suggests, why is that the mean forecasting error is minimised when conditional expectation is used for forecasting in ARMA model?

Need some guidance on this..

Comment: See this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52631/conditional-expectation-has-the-minimum-mean-prediction-error/52663#52663